# Crystal reports supress row is text "like"

Tags: crystal-reports

This is something that I just don't get.
My details contain a list of events. 
And in the Supress of the Details I have the following formula.
Why the following code works

```
 {@Event} like 'Event_1*' or
 {@Event} like 'Event_2*' or
 {@Event} like 'Event_3*' or
 {@Event} like "-"
```

and I get only the events which their names are NOT "Event1-3" or "-"
but the following code is not working and the detail section is suppressed even though I there are events named "Event1-3"

```
(Not({@Event} like 'Event_1*')) or
(Not({@Event} like 'Event_2*')) or
(Not({@Event} like 'Event_3*')) or
{@Event} like "-"
```

What I want to do is **suppress** all of the events that their names are **NOT** "Event1-3"

Thank you very much for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic boolen algebra - to negate entire expression `A or B` you can use either `not(A or B)` or `not A and not B` :)